# Clearing dropdown selection office-ui-fabric react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx-react, office-ui-fabric

Im having problem clearing selections in dropdown list. I sometime have to clear the selection of a dropdown since the options population changes. If a new options length is lesser than the previous one then the selection points outside the range giving error.

Simple example:
(See: [https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#Variants][1])

```js
<Dropdown
              selectedKey={ selectedItem && selectedItem.key }
              onChanged={ item => this.setState({selectedItem: item}) }
              options={
                [
                  { key: 'A', text: 'Option a' },
                  { key: 'B', text: 'Option b' },
                ]
              }
/>
```

The only thing I can think of is that maybe controlling selectedKey, ie setting selectedItem.key to null/undefined to clear it but Im not getting any luck with that solution..

Comment: same issue here... any solution yet?

Comment: Yes sorry, ill post a more thurough answer in an hour or so. Just make sure that your key is Null and the options is changed both before a render. My problem was my mix and/or lack of knowledge of mobx and how it triggered rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I had was that I did not change my options and the selected id at the same time. What I did was that I associate each dropdown with an object:

```js
// ...async call .then( (newFruits) => ...
this.fruits = {
  selectedId: null,
  options: ['My','newly', 'fetched','fruits','array']
};
```

...where fruits would be your observable Array.

```html
<Dropdown
    selectedKey={ fruits && fruits.selectedId }
    onChanged={ this.myFuncThatCallsApiWithNewId }
    options={fruits.options}
/>
```